# Deleted FMDB bridge file causes error in project navigator

Tags: swift, fmdb, bridge, xcode6.1.1

I have applied FMDB database wrapper in my project. I added FMDB bridging files in a Group folder named "FMDB" in my project navigator. "FMDB" folder also had "myprojectname-Bridging-Header.h" file. Accidentally i deleted the "FMDB" folder from my project navigator and added them(bridging files) again in the navigator's root folder. Then i got error like -

```
error: bridging header '/Users/nascenia/Documents/iPhone/bhoganti/bhoganti-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist
```

Then i deleted all those bridging file from my project's root folder as well as from finder and added "FMDB" folder again with those bridging files in the root folder of my project. But I still have that issue. Please let me know what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issues by following steps :

1. removed bridging header and all related file . . .
2. Clean Build/Solution. Cmd + Shift + k like . . .
3. Create new Objective-C file for bridging header file creation . . .
4. Now, add your others file . . .